# ObjectTranslations deployment succeeds but field labels do not change. How to resolve?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, customobjecttranslation

I am trying to deploy ObjectTranslations via SFDX and the deployment seems to successfully work but no change is occurring in the target org. If I try to deploy a translation contract_end_date.fieldTranslation-meta.xml containing the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomFieldTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <caseValues>
        <plural>false</plural>
        <value>Expected Contract End Date</value>
    </caseValues>
    <name>contract_end_date</name>
    <startsWith>Consonant</startsWith>
</CustomFieldTranslation>
```

The deployment returns the following

=== Deployed Source
22:47:08.478 Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

=== Deployed Source
22:47:11.187 ended SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

but no changes occur.  I was thinking I may need to deploy an associated
Contract-en_US.objectTranslation-meta.xml file as well but this did not have an impact.

For deploying object translations are there additional requirements for doing so?  Any tips on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your name field doesn't look right -- if a custom field, needs to end with `__c`; also, the xml doesn't tell what custom object the custom field translation belongs to -- see [example at end](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm?q=customfieldtranslation#customFieldTranslation)

Comment: Thank you. My field is  the standard EndDate (Contract End Date) (from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Contract.htm)  On retrieving customObjectTranslations it generated the above XML for me for the EndDate.

Comment: odd - apiName for that field is `EndDate`

Comment: Yes, It looks like it has retrieved the Label alone, without any API name.